# I'm trying to display an array containing data from a json file + more data I added, but it only shows data from the json file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a form to get all the fields of data from the user but when I try to display it only the json file data is showing I can't get the data I push into clients array to display
I'm sure the data is added to the clients array since I can log it in the console.

html view:

```
<div ng-controller="adminCtrl" class="listClients">
    <h1>Liste des clients :</h1>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="client in clients">
          <h3>{{client.numClient}} - {{client.rue}}</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

app.js

```
myApp.controller('adminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location',function($scope, $http, $location){

  //get clients in arr clients
  $http.get("data/clients.json").then(function(response){
      $scope.clients = response.data;
  }); // clients is an array containing all clients from clients.json

  

  //add newclient
  $scope.addClient = function(){
    $scope.clients.push ({
       numClient: parseInt($scope.newclient.numClient),
       rue: $scope.newclient.rue,
       numRue: parseInt($scope.newclient.numRue),
       codePostal: parseInt($scope.newclient.codePostal),
       localite: $scope.newclient.localite,
       available: true
   });

    $scope.newclient.numClient = "";
    $scope.newclient.rue = "";
    $scope.newclient.numRue = "";
    $scope.newclient.codePostal = "";
    $scope.newclient.localite = "";
    

  };


}]);
```

Comment: What is $scope.newClient where you get that data from?

Comment: i got it from a form that I got the user to fill out:                                                      
 '<form ng-controller="adminCtrl" ng-submit="addClient()">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Numero client" ng-model="newclient.numClient" />'

Comment: @MohamedDouzi Judging from your comment it sounds like you have created two separate `adminCtrl` instances and the scope from the one populating your list is not the scope that the form is pushing values into.